Add option to make "log out of all devices" the default
When logging out, I always click on the checkbox saying "log out of all devices". And I do this multiple times a day.
So I want there to be an option to make this checkbox already selected by default.
Basically, please add an option in the settings menu of the user profile, to choose whether the user wants to make this checkbox on by default or not.
That would reduce the time and effort that it takes to check this box every time I log out.



so there should be a checkbox to make the other checkbox on by default? Just do the extra click, there are far more important feature requests.

@M-- In a great cosmic act of irony, it wouldn't surprise me if we got something like this, but not elementary onboarding or other critical upgrades  or features

That's some supreme bike shedding here. Bravo!

https://stackoverflow.com/q/47743629/238704

Wow, people here think features that are actually useful and needed in 2024 in any real site like this one and the other one Adding Security log option for seeing login activites and two factor auth are not important(or less important) or not worth it.

@M-- It should not be any difficult to provide an option in the user settings menu to provide an option to make this on by default.

@M-- "Just do the extra click...." That's what we've been doing as already mentioned in the post. That's the whole reason for the feature request. And there are always more important feature request but that doesn't mean this feature request isn't needed/required. But yes, feature requests are also somewhat subjective issue, some might find one feature more useful than others so not all will agree for a given feature request.

I exactly meant just keep doing what you mentioned you are doing. An extra click is not a burden at all. And your FR  is hardly needed. I don't think many users want to log out everywhere that often. Moreover, considering that resources are limited, we do need to focus on features that are found more useful (putting aside what I said about this feature being a very niche "need"). Score of +1 /-15 should tell you that this is very much not needed, at least not by many users.

@M--  Yeah, as I said many users might not find it useful and they can downvote based on that. There's nothing wrong with downvoting as it indicates whether they find the FR useful or not. But as always there might be users like me that find this FR and this one useful. The latter is a must imo for any real site in 2024.

I don't understand what's the point of bringing up another FR of yours. OK, that one is useful. I agree (+1 on that). But this one isn't, imo. And users can vote as well as leaving comments reflecting their opinion. Anyway, I don't think our conversation is adding any value to the site or to our lives. I will leave it here. Cheers.

I haven't tried, but I'd guess you could use a userscript for this. You'd use an extension like Tampermonkey. There's a bunch of userscripts on "StackApps" for an idea of userscripts. Feel free to ping me if you need help there.

@cocomac I'll check it out and ping if need be.

I created a userscript that does this for you. It marks the checkbox checked by default when you navigate to the logout page.
See on Stack Apps: Logout from all devices by default
For instructions on how to install a userscript manager, see the [script] tag wiki on Stack Apps.

Installation
Direct install (GitHub)
See the code on GitHub
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Logout from all devices by default
// @description     Mark "log out of all devices" by default when logging out of Stack Exchange sites
// @namespace       Violentmonkey Scripts
// @grant           none
// @inject-into     page
// @match           https://stackoverflow.com/users/logout
// @match           https://serverfault.com/users/logout
// @match           https://superuser.com/users/logout
// @match           https://*.stackexchange.com/users/logout
// @match           https://askubuntu.com/users/logout
// @match           https://stackapps.com/users/logout
// @match           https://mathoverflow.net/users/logout
// @match           https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/logout
// @match           https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/logout
// @match           https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/logout
// @match           https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/logout
// @match           https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/logout
// @match           https://meta.serverfault.com/users/logout
// @match           https://meta.superuser.com/users/logout
// @match           https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/logout
// @match           https://meta.mathoverflow.net/users/logout
// @match           https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/logout
// @match           https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/logout
// @match           https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/logout
// @match           https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/logout
// @match           https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/users/logout
// @namespace       https://github.com/PurpleMagick/
// @version         1.0
// @author          VLAZ
// ==/UserScript==
(function() {
    document.querySelector("#everywhere").checked = true;
})();

